# Download multiple images with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to download lot of files form few websites at once, I have this code

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var arr = ['http://www.bonyfarma.com/images/Bony%20Air.jpg', 'http://www.bonyfarma.com/images/Bony%20A-Booster.jpg'];

for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(arr[i].split('/').pop(-1).toLowerCase().replace("%20", "-"));
    var request = http.get(arr[i], function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
    });
};
```

But e.g. when I run this code, the first file is empty, only second file is downloaded.. Can you help me with fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var arr = ['http://www.bonyfarma.com/images/Bony%20Air.jpg', 'http://www.bonyfarma.com/images/Bony%20A-Booster.jpg'];

for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    (function(url){
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(url.split('/').pop(-1).toLowerCase().replace("%20", "-"));
        http.get(url, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
        });
    })(arr[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this is that your `file` variable get's hoisted outside of the `for` loop. This results in all the responses piping to the last stream created.

Easiest way to fix this is by properly scoping the var using a simple `Array.prototype.forEach` (node supports this):

```
arr.forEach(function(url) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(url.split('/').pop(-1).toLowerCase().replace("%20", "-"));
    var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
    });
});
```